# How to add a custom button to the Quick Look toolbar in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf, quicklook

I'm currently displaying a PDF file using the Quick Look framework on an iPad via the Modal View Controller.  Works great.  My problem is that since I'm displaying a PDF file the Quick Look preview is automatically adding a "Print" button.  What I would like to do is replace the "Print" button with a custom "Email" button.  Is this something that can be done?  At first pass I thought this was going to be a somewhat trivial thing to do but at this point I'm really struggling with it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 1):

Since QLPreviewController is a subclass of UIViewController, you can take advantage of -[UIViewController setToolbarItems:] to customize the toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(emailPDF)]; 
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
[previewController setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];   
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

Now when the user taps the "reply" icon in the toolbar, your implementation of -emailPDF will get called.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!  I can't get this to work.  Seems like it should but I must be missing something.  I'm new to Objective-C.  `QLPreviewController * ql = [[[QLPreviewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 ql.dataSource = self;
 ql.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row;
 UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(emailPDF)]; 
 NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];
 [ql setToolbarItems:items animated:NO];   
 [self presentModalViewController:ql animated:YES];`

Comment: Try: [self setToolbarHidden:NO]. UINavigationController's toolbarHidden property is set to YES by default.

Comment: Even with the setToolbarHidden:No I'm not having any luck.  I can see the toolbar.  It's just not responding to the updated UIBarButtonItem.  I wonder if I need to override it somehow?  I also wonder if it could be how I'm building the PDF preview.  In your code sample I see where you specify '[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
'.  For me that doesn't work.  I can only get it to work if I use '[self presentModalViewController:ql animated:YES];'  Am I possibly doing something wrong with how I set the QLPreviewController?

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this.  In your example is previewController a UINavigationController or a UIViewController?  I'm sorry this is probably a very "newb" question.  Thanks.

Comment: The previewController is an instance of QLPreviewController. I was calling this code from the AppDelegate, so I'm calling presentModalViewControler:animated: on the navigationController (An instance of UINavigationController) of the AppDelegate.

Comment: Try downloading Apple's sample code for DocInteraction: developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/…. Then, in DTTableViewController, add the following to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemReply target:self action:@selector(emailPDF)]; NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item]; [previewController setToolbarItems:items animated:NO]; [item release];

Comment: Stephen you rock, I'll take a look right now.  Thank you again for your help with this.  I'll post how it goes.

Comment: I'm understanding this better now but I still can't get the "reply" icon in the upper right corner of the PDF preview to call the emailPDF function.  I have all of the code together under the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  Here's the DITableViewControler m file that I've updated.  [link](http://www.ceilink.com/transfer/DITableViewController.txt)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a subclass of QLPreviewController like MyQLPreviewController

Then in viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated (IMPORTANT!!)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightRatain = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *email = ...;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:right, email, nil];
    [email release];
}
```